# Leaflet GeoJSON filters

Tags: javascript, json, filter, leaflet, filtering

I have managed to get the below working with help from people on here but stuck at a JS problem. Currently, my problem is the map now only shows the two markers where carp and tench both = 1 in the GeoJSON. What I am trying to do is something more dynamic:

1. I'd like to have the checkboxes off as default
2. I'd also like to fix the problem where only the results that match carp = 1 and tench = 1 show on the map. I'd like the filter to be dynamic with each selection instead of restricting the results from the off

https://jsfiddle.net/chrisjenner/0ez7k8um/

Filter code:

```
<div class="input" id="carp">
      <input type="checkbox" class="carp" name="1" value="1" checked="true">
      <label for="1">Carp</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input" id="tench">
      <input type="checkbox" class="tench" name="2" value="1" checked="true">
      <label for="2">Tench</label>
    </div>

const lakes = L.geoJSON(null, {
  style: function(feature) {
    return {
      color: feature.properties.color
    };
  },
  filter: (feature) => {
    const isCarpChecked = checkboxStates.carp.includes(feature.properties.carp)
    const isTenchChecked = checkboxStates.tench.includes(feature.properties.tench)
    return isCarpChecked && isTenchChecked //only true if both are true
  }
}).bindPopup(function(layer) {
  return layer.feature.properties.name;
}).addTo(map);

function updateCheckboxStates() {
  checkboxStates = {
    carp: [],
    tench: []
  }

for (let input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
    if (input.checked) {
      var numValue = parseInt(input.value);
      switch (input.className) {
        case 'carp':
          checkboxStates.carp.push(numValue);
          break
        case 'tench':
          checkboxStates.tench.push(numValue);
          break
      }
    }
  }
}

for (let input of document.querySelectorAll('input')) {
    input.onchange = (e) => {
    lakes.clearLayers()
    updateCheckboxStates()
    lakes.addData(lakes_data)
  }
}


updateCheckboxStates()
lakes.addData(lakes_data)
```

Comment: Do you want to have checkboxes with the other categories as wel like bream, roach ... parking etc and filter all of them at the same time?

Comment: Hi @kboul that's exactly what I want but tried to keep it simple and hoped I'd be able to extend whatever someone put forward as a suggestion.